# MSSQL insertWITHRELATIONSHIP

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error while inserting a record on my 2 tables with relationship key.  Here are my tables:

table name is [tbl1]

```
Ccode bigint, (autoincrement) (not null) ----->relationship with tbl2
customerId varchar(5), (not null)   
CUstomerName varchar(50)
```

table name is [tbl2]

```
User_Idx bigint, (autoincrement) (not null)
Ccode bigint, (autoincrement) (not null)  ----->relationship with tbl1 
callLogs bit, (yes/no or 0/1) (not null)
MyDateTime DateTime, (not null)
Duration smalldatetime, 
Description varchar20
```

here is my Insert Query but did not work :(

```
insert into tbl1 values ('5055','Vangelyn De Castro')
insert into tbl2 values ('1','01/26/16 08:40', '24:12:00','Incoming Call')
```

Comment: There are a lot of "fishy" things here; You're using double quotes `"` in your SQL instead of single quotes `'`, you have a time of `24:12:00` which is more hours than exist in a day, you're not saying which fields to insert a'la `insert into tbl1(customerId, customerName) VALUES (...` which you need to do if not inserting _all_ fields including `ccode`, but it's all very hard to know what is a result of constructing the example and what is the actual error since you're not giving a specific error message. Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: insert into tbl1 values ('5055','Vangelyn De Castro')
insert into tbl2 values ('1','01/26/16 08:40', '24:12:00','Incoming Call')

Comment: sorry i forgot i single quoted it :)

Comment: Try `insert into tbl1(customerId, customerName) VALUES ('5055','Vangelyn De Castro')` since you don't want to give values for all fields.

Comment: insert into tbl1 values ('5055','Vangelyn De Castro')
insert into tbl2 values ('1','01/26/16 08:40', '24:12:00','Incoming Call') ****still im getting an error it says cannot convert into varbinary etc :(

Comment: "cannot convert into varbinary etc" is not an error please take the time to edit your original post and put in the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is just a basic schema issue.

table 2 with ccode should not be autoincrement as table1 holds the unique value for ccode..

```
table2 ccode bigint, (not null)  -- that's it.
```